# Can't use PBEWithHmacSHA1AndDESede with Bouncy Castle fips jar, works fine with RSA cryptoJ

Tags: java, bouncycastle, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have a code that creates a key using algorithm PBEWithHmacSHA1AndDESede

```
SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA1AndDESede");
```

The above works fine with RSA JSAFE JCE but doesnot with BouncyCastle Fips Jar.

What would be the algorithm for bouncycastle that matches PBEWithHmacSHA1AndDESede of RSA?

Answer (score 0):

`PBEWithHmacSHA1AndDESede` translates to `DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding` cipher with secret key created with `PBKDF2withHmacSHA1`

```
SecretKeyFactory kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(
    "PBKDF2withHmacSHA1", "BCFIPS");

Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BCFIPS");
```